# VB.net Reading from ListViews with Multiple Columns

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview

Alright. So I was able to find out how to read from the first column but I need to read from both of them. I am using full row select which I need on there.

Here is the code I am using to get it for the first column.

```
Dim I As Integer
For I = 0 To ListView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
    MsgBox(ListView1.SelectedItems(I).Text)
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim's answer is correct this is just a variant of it:

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
    Debug.WriteLine("Col1 {0}, Col2 {1}", item.Text, item.SubItems(1).Text)
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

The Column(s) text is located in the SubItem array of the list view item.

so you would do something like...(VB is not my 1st language so this is untested)

```
dim i as Integer
dim item as ListViewItem
for i = 0 to ListView1.SelectedItems.Count -1
  item = ListView1.SelectedItems(i)
  Console.WriteLine(Col1 = {0} Col2 = {1},item.SubItems(0),item.SubItems(1))
next
```

(note, usually not a good idea to pop up a messagebox in a loop)