# How do I create and populate a 3 column ListView?

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-web-developer-2010

I need to create and populate a ListView with 3 strings that come from another function.  I also want to be able to select multiple pieces of the data to change their values during runtime (is that possible with ListView?).

I've looked all over online for info on this, but I can't seem to find any.  If someone would could give me some insight on the best way to do this, I would really appreciate it.

I've seen somethings on GridView as well.  Would that be better for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that i've no clue what you're actually asking. But yes, you can bind 3 Strings to a `ListView` coming from "another function" :)

You can handle [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) to change values in the ListItems:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        A String
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <asp:Label ID="LblString" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The page's codebehind:

```
Public Class ListView
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Me.ListView1.DataSource = OtherFuntion()
            Me.ListView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function OtherFuntion() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Return {"String 1", "String 2", "String 3"}
    End Function

    Private Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            Dim lblString = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("LblString"), Label)
            lblString.Text = New String(lblString.Text.Reverse.ToArray)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This simply reverses all strings.

Comment: the question is tagged vb.net and the answer is about asp.net

Comment: @emaillenin: What has the technology to do with the language? I would agree if the OP has tagged Winforms.

Comment: because your answer does not seem to answer the question.. here is the actual answer for this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846462/vb-net-reading-from-listviews-with-multiple-columns

Comment: @emaillenin: But OP has tagged visual-web-developer-2010. He also mentioned `GridView` which is a WebControl. Therefor i've assumed that the question targets the ASP.NET `ListView` and not Winforms.